# Why does my object not show up in View Port Shading?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm very new to Blender. What is every reason an object isn't showing up in a render or viewport in when using the cycles render engine? I've been trying to figure it out but the object is still disappeared. Please advise.

[image]

After I inserted light in my scene.The object still doesn't show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a light into your scene. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then Light to add a light.

In order to view an object, you'll need some light for the object to bounce back to you!

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I inserted a light to the scene but the object still doesn't show up in Render Cycles.

Comment: You should share your file to take a look at it

Comment: I've edited and added a screenshot to my question for your reference. 
Thank you @Emir